# Help Ubuntu 17.10 sound drops

Tags: sound, 17.10

I closed the lid of my laptop, when I opened it, there's no sound from speakers or headphones.

It also happens if I boot Windows and restart to boot Ubuntu. If I shutdown the computer and turn on then boot with Ubuntu and the sound works fine.

I've followed the instructions I could find on askubuntu, and Sound Troubleshooting Procedure yet nothing works.
Please help.
[image]
[image]

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" > /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf
bash: /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf: Permission denied

$ sudo lspci -v
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
    Memory at a4428000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a4410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if it works. The command below will load your snd-hda-intel module by appending it to /etc/modules, you might need to do a log off/log in.
    `echo "snd-hda-intel" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

Comment: Thanks, @root. That "kind of works". That makes the headphones work but not the speaker for both music on my computer and online (youtube, spotify...)

Comment: You forgot to put your system specs, but anyway, this document may be helpful. Follow the instruction to diagnose the problem and then append the `options snd-hda-intel model=YOUR_MODEL` to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file. https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel

Comment: I've updated the specs above. I've tried with model=ALC295 Analog but permission denied.

Comment: You need root access `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, then append the options line.

Comment: It worked, but then I restarted my computer and again there's no speaker sound.

Comment: I looked at your edited post, and you have this line `sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" > /etc/modprobe.d/snd-hda-intel.conf`; this is different from appending to a file. What this line does is overwriting the config file with the newly added line. That could cause the new problems that you have.

Comment: It didn't go through, permission denied.